# Get the identifier number along with the string inside the identifier using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

Need to identify the number inside the identifier, along with the text between the identifiers.

`(?<=\[\[(\d)\]\])(.*?)(?=\[\[\\\1\]\])` - Returns the text between the identifiers, but I also need the number inside the identifier.

Link of what I have so far: https://regex101.com/r/W8lZST/6

This function is triggered on keyup.

```js
function getWords(editorName, blank) {
  var choicesTemp = [];
  choicesTemp = $("#" + editorName).html().match(/(?<=\[\[(\d+)\]\])(.*?)(?=\[\[\\\1\]\])/gm);
  if (choicesTemp == null || blank === true) choicesTemp = [];
  var uniqueTemp = [];
  $.each(choicesTemp, function(i, el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, uniqueTemp) === -1) uniqueTemp.push(el);
  });
  choicesTemp = uniqueTemp;
  return choicesTemp;
}
```

String: `[[1]] abc [[\1]] [[2]] pqr [[\2]] xyz [[3]] rst [[\3]] [[5]] ijk [[\5]]`

Actual:

```
text: abc,
text: pqr, 
text: rst,
```

Expected:

```
    text: abc,
    number: 1,

    text: pqr, 
    number: 2,

    text: rst,
    number: 3
```

Comment: You already capture the digit in the lookbehind. Get it from the match object. Show your code. Note `/\[\[(\d+)]](.*?)\[\[\\\1\]]/g` can be used, too, no lookarounds are necessary here. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r15kew/1).

Comment: Is your 'actual' an array or a string with substrings?

Comment: Please look at my code and let me know how can I get the match object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a simpler regex with no lookarounds and grab the captured parts to populate the associative array:

```js
var choicesTemp = [], m;
var reg = /\[\[(\d+)]](.*?)\[\[\\\1\]]/g;
var s = "[[1]] abc [[\\1]] [[2]] pqr [[\\2]] xyz [[3]] rst [[\\3]] [[5]] ijk [[\\5]]" // $("#" + editorName).html(); 
while (m = reg.exec(s)) {
    var new_el = {};
    new_el['number'] = Number(m[1]);
    new_el['text'] = m[2].trim();
    choicesTemp.push(new_el);
}
console.log(choicesTemp); // this is what your function returns
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r15kew/1).

Comment: I first got the string inclusive of the number and then separated the two using regex.

Comment: It helped me, but I went by another way.

Comment: Hi, New requirement: If a number is already used, it cannot be used in another identifier, for ex: if 1 is used already, it can not be used in another identifier. Is this possible inside the regex??